# Grant select on a table forcing WHERE

Tags: oracle, procedure, ora-06550

I have a table with users data (email, name, surname, username, password..) and I want to grant each user to see only his own data (like seeing his profile). I have been trying to do it this way:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE PR_OWNDATA AS
BEGIN
 FOR userRow IN (SELECT COD_USUARIO, USERNAME FROM CAMP.USERS) LOOP
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON CAMP.USERS TO "' || userRow.USERNAME || '" WHERE COD_USUARIO = ' || userRow.COD_USUARIO || ';';
 END LOOP;
END PR_OWNDATA;
```

It doesn't work (ORA 06550 "line %s, column %s:\n%s"). But I can't see where is the problem..

I have think about create a VIEW per USER in this way

```
CREATE VIEW userRow.USERNAME.V_DATOSALUMNO AS SELECT * FROM CAMP.USERS WHERE COD_USUARIO = ' || userRow.COD_USUARIO || ';';
```

But I don't know if it is the correct way..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to search for 'Oracle row-level security'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the name you're giving to the view, but the code should be:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view_name
AS
SELECT *
FROM   CAMP.USERS
WHERE  COD_USUARIO = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')
```

Of course if you're not salting and hashing that password then you're doing it all wrong.